# AWS WorkMail - can send emails but not receive them

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, imap

so I configured AWS Workmail for my business email and added all of the DNS records that the configuration process provided me with. Looks good so far - I can send emails to my gmail account. But when I answer from my gmail account to the AWS WorkMail email, I don't get the mail to my inbox. Also I don't get an error mail back to my gmail account, it just "disappears". Does anyone know why this is happening? The DNS records seem correct ...

I already tried to redo all of the process but with the same effect. Also I tried disabling and enabling the user I created.

Thanks in advance!